# Does SQLite3 have prepared statements in Node.js?

Tags: sql, node.js, express, sqlite, prepared-statement

From the npm docs, only visible prepared statements are for insert. Does these prepared statement work for Select, update, and delete?

I tried for select, there isn't a `.each` function where the rows are called back. Anyone been able to do this or have links to resources, cause I can sure as hell unable to find any.

Comment: I have noticed the same thing when testing with mapbox/node-sqlite3 that I don't get data back when using prepared statements for SELECT, only INSERT. DELETE is working for me as a prepared statement but in my case my query isn't trying to return anything when I delete.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the [node-sqlite3 API documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback), you can use parameters in your SQL queries in several different ways:

```
// Directly in the function arguments.
db.run("UPDATE tbl SET name = ? WHERE id = ?", "bar", 2);

// As an array.
db.run("UPDATE tbl SET name = ? WHERE id = ?", [ "bar", 2 ]);

// As an object with named parameters.
db.run("UPDATE tbl SET name = $name WHERE id = $id", {
  $id: 2,
  $name: "bar"
});
```

Comment: Izc is asking about prepared statements that use SELECT, this shows a workaround but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, prepared statements are supported.

With [node-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3):

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('data.db');

db.serialize(function() {

  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("user " + i, "email " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
  stmt.each(userId, function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.name, row.email);
  }, function(err, count) {
      stmt.finalize();
  });

});
```

With [better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3):

```
var Database = require('better-sqlite3');
var db = new Database('foobar.db', options);

var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    stmt.run("user " + i, "email " + i);
}

var stmt = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?');
var row = stmt.get(userId);
console.log(row.name, row.email);
```